# Picamera (in Terminal and Python 3) just does nothing

Tags: pi-3, raspicam, vnc, python-3

I have a Picamera V2, a brand new Flex Cable (so that's not the problem) and a Pi 3B.

I am using VNC from Ubuntu. The Pi connects OK. But in the terminal (`raspistill - o hi.jpg`) and in Python 3

(

```
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep

camera = PiCamera()

camera.start_preview()
sleep(1)
camera.stop_preview()
```

)

it just waits there (without showing an error message). **It doesn't stop without being killed**

Comment: So you get no output at all? Try `raspistill -v -o hi.jpg`. It should give you some debug output

Answer (score 1):

Normally camera output will not show over VNC. It bypasses the framebuffer so VNC cannot capture it. If you have a screen directly connected to the Pi you would see the camera output on that.

RealVNC has an experimental feature that *will* capture the camera output. It works, but it's not great.

https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/docs/raspberry-pi.html describes how to enable it. Look for 'experimental direct capture' on that page.

Comment: see my edit please

Comment: @RHarrington Is it supposed to stop by itself? You will have to post your code / commands